# Adding arraylist in UserSetting

Tags: c#, winforms, arraylist, settings

I want to add a new usersetting to my application (an arraylist), but in "Type" i can't find the arraylist type in the list:

[image]

Also when i try to find this type, i can't find System.Collections where arraylist is defined:

[image]

Is there any way to add arraylist type to usersetting?
Thank you

Comment: What's the problem with `System.Collections.Specialized.StringCollection`? What's your actual requirement?

Comment: there is an error when i do "Settings.Default.cboCollection = arraylist;"

Comment: Surely such assignment is not valid. I mean using a `System.Collections.Specialized.StringCollection`. What's your actual requirement?

Comment: i want to save the items of a combobox permenantly so i found a solution that implement usersetting, i follow it.

Comment: The most simple option for you is using `System.Collections.Specialized.StringCollection`. Also you can simply store comma delimited list of items in a string property.

Comment: ok Reza! it's done with stringcollection. Thank you all